# Trying to Combine Values in Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I Have an Array Below which I run a foreach to get values from a mysql database $pn_list is the Array above the PHP code. I am trying to get where the the 'gen_buy_len' is the same I add together 'gen_buy_qty'. I Get the Results Below. Any help appreciated.

```
Array
(
    [2099] => 2099
    [2906] => 2906
)


foreach($pn_list as $pn){
    SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `MPL`.`MPL` WHERE `job` = '$job' AND `qb_pn` = $pn");
    $results = SQL::Results();
    $arr = array();
    foreach($results as $k => $value){
      $key = $pn . ":" . $value['gen_buy_len'];
      $arr[$key] += $value['gen_buy_qty'];
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

My Results:

```
Notice:  Undefined index: 2099:240 in /var/www/html/procurement/html/mpl.php on line 75



Notice:  Undefined index: 2906:504 in /var/www/html/procurement/html/mpl.php on line 75

Array
(
    [2906:504] => 1
)
```

My Goal:

```
Array
(
     [2099:240] = 5 //These Are Two  $value['gen_buy_qty'] added together from DB
     [2906:480] = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `foreach` block to be as follows:

```
foreach($pn_list as $pn){
    SQL::Query("SELECT * FROM `MPL`.`MPL` WHERE `job` = '$job' AND `qb_pn` = $pn");
    $results = SQL::Results();
    $arr = array();
    foreach($results as $k => $value){
        $key = $pn . ":" . $value['gen_buy_len'];
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
            $arr[$key] = 0;
        }
        $arr[$key] += $value['gen_buy_qty'];
    }
}
```

This should initialize the array's key in case it isn't present yet, so you cant start adding values to it.

Comment: I Get the error Warning:  array_key_exists() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given, When I add the Array $arr or $value I Only Get One Line the Array
(
    [2100:240] => 20
)

Comment: WHOOPS! Sorry! Small mistake from me, I have no way to test this code from here. Updated now, please see if you get any more errors.